# How to send email using template in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to send email using template. I have tried this code but it gives this error.

*Severity: 4096
Message: Object of class CI_Loader could not be converted to string*

My code is:

```
public function email_submit_change_password(){
    $this->load->library('email');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');   

    $check = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_profile_main WHERE connect_to_email='".$email."';");
    if($check->result()!=NULL){
        $test = $this->load->view('includes/test');
        $this->email->from('itsthunder07@gmail.com', 'Your Name');
        $this->email->to($email);   
        $this->email->subject('Password Reset');
        $this->email->message($test);
        if($this->email->send()){
        $this->db->query("UPDATE tbl_profile_main SET token_='".$token."' WHERE connect_to_email='".$email."';");   
        $this->session->set_userdata('email_send','success');
        return 1;
        // return 5;
    }
    }else{
        $this->session->set_userdata('email_incorrect','error');
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: any line number it specified in error ? i also find `$test = $this->load->view('includes/test', '' , true);` it will return html in `$test` instead of appending to response.

Comment: it worked, but the whole webpage is not displayed in the mail only text and links are displayed. (CSS Stylings are not displayed).

Comment: you need to use inline css for email. Email don't allow css loading like we do in normal html. for further help you should post your `includes/test.php` file code.

Comment: @SandeepPariyar comment all code and just `echo $test` and check view is loaded

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return a view as a string, you have to load it as follows:

```
$test = $this->load->view('includes/test', '', true);
```

Comment: it worked, but the whole webpage is not displayed in the mail only text and links are displayed. (CSS Stylings are not displayed).

Answer (score 0):

there should be check like this:

```
<?php
$check = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_profile_main WHERE connect_to_email='".$email."';");
if($check->num_rows() > 0) { // check data exists or not
    $r = $check->result_array();
    if(!empty($r)) {
        // send email process
    } else {
        $this->session->set_userdata('email_incorrect','error');
        return 0;
    }
}
?>
```